# Sending images to S3 as a POST method from node js s3 client

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am creating a lambda which will trigger once a image is pushed to a S3 bucket and create its thumbnail. The requirement is that the thumbnail needs to be saved in the same directory as the original image.
So to prevent loop-back of lambda the approach we came up with is that that the other system sending the original image is doing so by using PUT method. And we wanted to send the generated thumbnail from lambda as a POST method.
From what I checked I see that the S3 node client also sends data as a PUT method. And all I see in the documentation are put methods.
Is there a way to change this and instead send the objects using POST method from lambda using node S3 client?

Comment: It would probably be easier if you had some pattern you could have your lambda ignore.  For instance, have the lambda create thumbnails that always end in '_tn.jpg', and if is ever launched with such a filename, just exit without doing anything.

Comment: So the image could be of any extension. So that option is also not viable here.

Comment: You don't check the extension but just check the whether the filename without extension ends with "_tn".  See if this can be done, otherwise even this method is also flawed when the original file name already has "_tn" at the end of filename

Comment: If you're using a bucket event notification to trigger your Lambda, you could prefix all of your original images with `o_`, for example and then create a prefix filter which will only trigger your Lambda when an object with that prefix is created. This would support your requirement of multiple extensions/file types as we're checking the start of the key not the end.